# How to generate a sqlite3-compatible dump from Propel's schema.xml

Tags: sqlite, symfony, phpunit, propel

To speed up the unit tests I want to use SQLite instead of MySQL, so I'm trying to get a SQLite-compatible dump of the databases from Propel's schema.xml. The application is built in Symfony2, and this is how the db configuration in `config.yml` looks like:

```
propel:
    dbal:
        driver:               sqlite            
        dsn:                  sqlite:/tmp/test_db1.sq3
        default_connection:   db1
        connections:
           db1:
               user:           %database_user%
               password:       %database_password%
               dsn: sqlite:/tmp/test_db1.sq3   
           db2:
               user:           %database_user%
               password:       %database_password%
               dsn: sqlite:/tmp/test_db2.sq
```

However, the command `app/console propel:build-sql` is always generating MySQL-specific dumps that fail to load into SQLite.

I've also removed any references to MySQL from properties.ini and still don't get it right.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each connection name has to be related to a database name, so if you declare a connection `c1`, you need to have a database tag with the attribute `name="c1"` (in your `schema.xml`).

Assuming you have the following `schema.xml`:

```
<database name="default">
    …
</database>
```

Write the following section in your `config.yml`:

```
propel:
    dbal:
        default_connection:   default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:               mysql            
                username:             root
                dsn:                  mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_db
```

And the following definition in `config_test.yml`:

```
propel:
    dbal:
        connections:
            default:
                driver:               sqlite            
                dsn:                  sqlite:/tmp/test_db1.sq3
```

Then, if you want to generate SQL statements for your tests, just run:

```
php app/console --env=test propel:build-sql
```

To generate SQL statements for your dev env:

```
php app/console propel:build-sql
```

or

```
php app/console --env=dev propel:build-sql
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! I think I was failing to override the driver in the connections themselves.